# How to solve $x \geq \frac{1}{\ln^p x}$?

Tags: calculus

How do I solve:

$$x \geq \ln^p x$$ $$(p, x \in \mathbb{R})$$

For $p > 1$ I get $x \geq e^{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}{p}]{x}}$ but I don't know how to continue... I'm confused, I don't remember how to solve such inequality

Comment: I'm afraid there is no closed form answer. However, for $x\geq e$ we have $1/\ln^p x<1<e\leq x$.

Comment: Use the Lambert $W$ function, to get: $x=\exp(p\cdot W(1/p))$.